# Spark Job aborted when trying to join two tuples with Generic Record as value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, left-join, spark-streaming

I am trying to do left outer join on two Dstreams and both are of type [k: String , V: GenericData.Record] but getting error

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) had a not serializable result: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record
```

Comment: `GenericData.Record` 
 does not seem to be Serializable indeed. See: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.Record.html

Comment: So any other way to make it work

Comment: I'm not familiar with AVRO + Spark but I would guess that there's a better way. Have you tried already AVRO support from DataBricks?  https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro